# Compile time error in stripe payment in flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment   `stripe_payment: ^1.0.0` in mt flutter app,
I am just integrating it to my app, i just add the dependency in pub , and trying to use following method on btn pressed:

```
StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(CardFormPaymentRequest()).then((paymentMethod) {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Received ${paymentMethod.id}')));
          setState(() {
            _paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
          });
        }).catchError(setError);
```

I just clean app and run ..but it gives following error

```
info flutter.tools  description: kIsWeb ? "Native Pay isn't supported in a web browser" :

pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stripe_payment-1.0.6/lib/src/stripe_payment.dart:32:9: Error: Getter not found: 'kIsWeb'.
```

Have also done

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```